# Передача параметров из множества диалоговых окона и равнозначное управление из каждого окна

Tags: c++, qt

Попытаюсь объяснить. У меня промышленный пк. С маленьким дисплеем 640 на 480. При запуски программы стартует главное окно из него есть переходы диалоговые окна. По типу диалоговое окно меню, ручное управление, график, и т.д. Открыл диалоговое окно меню. Из меню перешёл в настройки запустил второй поток передал через сигналы и слоты данные второго потока в главное окно. И закрыл диалог меню. Но не знаю как это сделать как передавать сигналы и слоты при работе с множеством диалоговых окон да и ещё каждое окно имеет равнозначные права по управлению.

Comment: Можете переписать ваш вопрос более подробно и понятно, а то он довольно сумбурный? Например, что за поток - его функция? Является ли он общим для нескольких диалоговых окон и так далее? Что значит равнозначные права по управлению? Чем лучше и понятнее опишите свою проблему, тем более точный получите ответ.

Comment: Каждое окно при открытии подписывается на сигналы главного окна, и главное окно подписывает на свои сигналы. Слоты главного окна просто транслируют сигналы всем подписчикам. т.е. все равнозначные окна ничего друг про друга не знают, и общаются через главное окно.